# How to remove selection after replace in vscode API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

while creating an extension for vscode I got stuck in selection, now the problem is when I replace some range of textEditor through an api it replaces that range as well as make that range selected. For snippets this is a good idea but my extension requirement is not to select replaced text, I searched in api but did't find anything related to remove text selection (Selection occurs when the document is empty)

```
editor.edit((editBuilder)=>{ //editor is an object of active text editor
        editBuilder.replace(textRange,text)   // text = 'dummydummydummy'
    }) //after this I got the following output
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```js
editor.edit(builder => {
    builder.replace(selection, newStr);
})
// The edit call returns a promise. When that resolves you can set 
// the selection otherwise you interfere with the edit itself. 
// So use "then" to sure edit call is done; 
.then(success => {
    console.log("success:", success);
    // Change the selection: start and end position of the new
    // selection is same, so it is not to select replaced text;
    var position = editor.selection.end; 
    editor.selection = new vscode.Selection(position, position);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is happening because the edit is being applied within the current selection. `edit` returns a promise that is resolved when the edit is applied, and you can use this to set the selection after the edit is successful:

```
editor.edit((editBuilder) => {
    editBuilder.replace(textRange, text)
}).then(success => {
    if (success) {
        // make selection empty
        editor.selection.active = editor.selection.anchor
    }
})
```

Comment: this didn't work, I also want to add to my question that whenever the document is empty the selection occurs in other cases it is working fine

Comment: I guess this is happening when range is not defined in the editor, I just want to know if there is anything like buffer changes in vscode which can be accessed through an api so that I can track previous selections

Answer (score 0):

```
let editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
let selection = editor.selection;
editor.edit(builder => {
    builder.replace(selection, newStr);
});
```

see: [TextEditorEdit API Doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#TextEditorEdit)

Comment: Could you also explain what this code does, and why it solves the problem? It could help others who come to visit the question and answers.

Comment: Don't know how this was up voted. It seems to just repeat what the OP was doing from the start of the question.