# VSCode API: Editor.edit editbuilder.replace fails without reason (possibly due to formatting?)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my extension I want to edit the document on a few specific document edits.

My actual use case is a bit complicated so I have created a minimal example. The code below listens for any document edit. If the word "hello" exists in the edit (i.e. the user pasted some code that contains the word "hello") then we replace the change range with the pasted text but just make it upper case.

We also `console.log` if the edit was successful, and any potential reason the edit was rejected.

```
vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument(event => {
    for (const change of event.contentChanges) {
        if (change.text.includes("hello")) {
            activeEditor.edit(editBuilder => {
                editBuilder.replace(change.range, change.text.toUpperCase());
            }).then(
                value => console.log("SUCCESS: "+value),
                reason => console.log("FAIL REASON: "+reason),
            );
        }
    }
});
```

A working example would be selecting some text in a document and pasting in the text `const hello = 5;`. As expected, the extension replaces the text with `CONST HELLO = 5;` and logs `SUCCESS: true`.

But when I paste in some text that automatically get formatted I run into problems. If I were to paste in:

```
    const hello = 5;
    const lol = 10;
    const lmao = 20;
```

Including all the whitespaces/tabs, then vscode wants to "format" or correct my lines, i.e. remove the whitespace. So the resulting text will be:

```
const hello = 5;
const lol = 10;
const lmao = 20;
```

The extension tries to make it uppercase still but only prints `SUCCESS: false`. No reason is logged at all; the reject function is not executed.

Why does the edit not succeed? Should I await the other edits somehow or keep re-trying the edit until it succeeds? Am I logging the rejection incorrectly?

Comment: you are not allowed to have overlapping regions in the edits, maybe VSC combines the edits of all the onDidChangeTextDocument providers and concludes an overlap

Comment: @rioV8 That is a good guess, and I was not aware of this restriction. But I do not think this is the error. I updated the example to add the word "Changed" to the first line of the document instead of making the text capitalized, and I still get the same problem. Code: https://pastebin.com/qPTPPHnA

Comment: don't store `activeEditor`, always fetch a new copy of the active editor, or see if the event has an editor property

Comment: @rioV8 Good idea. I forgot to mention that in my more extended project I generally do a check for the editor. I have updated the code to add that once more: https://pastebin.com/gwg4BTyF Sadly this did not fix my problem :(

Comment: is the event still valid when the editBuilder callback is called async, maybe construct local copies of the data you need from the event, for every change you create a new `editor.edit`, group them before the `edit` call and perform a loop of edits in the callback, have you printed the ranges that are part of the event

Comment: Because of the async nature of the `editBuilder` and especially see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87871#issuecomment-569651262 I would put the `editor.edit(editBuilder)` on the outside of the loop and then loop inside through your `contentChanges`.

Comment: @rioV8 Okay. I do not know how to check if the event is valid when the callback is called. Logging the event at the start of the code I can see that the initial paste is inserted, then vscode automatically change each row instantly in a second change: https://i.imgur.com/38XKnrP.png 
Regarding calling `editor.edit` multiple times, I restructured my examples like so: https://pastebin.com/u8hBikLM and it should only try call a single `edit` per `onDidChangeTextDocument` and is still behaving erroneously.

Should I be calling any function async?

Comment: Sorry, my above comment was an answer to you too @Mark.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps, here is code I use - I found it better to have the `editBuilder` outside the loop.  I think you can adapt it for your purposes:

```js
    editor.edit( (editBuilder) => {

      // put your for (const change of event.contentChanges) {} here

      for (const match of matches) {
        resolvedReplace = variables.buildReplace(args, "replace", match, editor.selection, null, index);

        const matchStartPos = document.positionAt(match.index);
        const matchEndPos = document.positionAt(match.index + match[0].length);
        const matchRange = new vscode.Range(matchStartPos, matchEndPos);

        editBuilder.replace(matchRange, resolvedReplace);
      }
    }).then(success => {
        if (!success) {
            return;
        }
        if (success) {  ... do something here if you need to }
    });
```

Comment: I changed my example to match your code structure: https://pastebin.com/yAKWYbgf

But my example with the three indented lines still does not work.

Comment: Does turning off `Editor: Format on Paste` help?

Comment: Actually... I had `Format on Paste` disabled. Enabling it makes the text not format on paste and the text is inserted as is (with indentation). Maybe this is because I am editing a typescript file and it has it's own formatter? Either way I would like it to work regardless of this option.

Comment: what is the reason/use of `if (success)`

Comment: @rioV8 You mean in general?  In my case I select certain user-defined text **after** the replacements have been made, if successfully.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71991706/836330 that is when the `cursorMoveSelect` option is performed.

Comment: The question is: What is the value of `success` in `if (success)`

Comment: @rioV8 `Thenable<boolean> 
A promise that resolves with a value indicating if the edits could be applied.`  true or false

Comment: See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/48335156/836330 from Matt B.

Comment: no, `success` is a `boolean`, and you already filtered out the `false` case so at `if (success)` the value of `success` is always `true`

Comment: @rioV8 For me, success is always `false` in the case of pasting in the three indented lines. The second callback function in `.then()` is never executed so it never logs the `reason` which I think is weird. I am not sure if I am using the callbaxks correctly?

Comment: @Zoom `TextEditor::edit` always returns a resolved `Thenable`, don't you get any message in the Developer Console (Help > Dev Tools) or Debug Console?

Comment: @rioV8 I only get the `console.log`s from the code in the debug console (`SUCCESS: false`). I have not checked any other console but will try to access them in ~5 hours.

Comment: @rioV8 Yes obviously, I am actually using `if (cursorMoveSelect)` in my code there not `if (success)` - I just put it there as psuedocode to make it clear where working code goes.

Comment: @rioV8 The dev tool console just prints the same information that is shown in my debug console: `[Extension Host] SUCCESS: false`. But thanks for informing me of this feature.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is just to "keep trying again". I do not like this solution, but it is a solution nevertheless, and it currently works for my use-case.

```js
    async function makeReplaceEdit(range: vscode.Range, text: string, maxRetries = 10) {
        for (let i = 0; i <= maxRetries; i++) {
            const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
            if (!editor) return;

            const success = await editor.edit(editBuilder => {
                editBuilder.replace(
                    range,
                    text
                );
            }, { undoStopBefore: false, undoStopAfter: false });

            if (success) break;
        }
    };

    vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument((event) => {

        // See if any change contained "hello"        
        let foundHello = false;
        for (const change of event.contentChanges) {
            if (change.text.includes("hello")) {
                foundHello = true;
            }
        }

        if (foundHello) {
            console.log("inside1");
            const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
            if (!editor) return;
            makeReplaceEdit(editor.document.lineAt(0).range, "Change");
        }
    });
```

Comment: maybe add a little timer and not keep hammering the edit system, 0.1 or 0.2 seconds, it will result in an infinite loop if the edit really is impossible, add a max number of tries

Comment: @rioV8 It seems like I can hammer it pretty well. I added a max number of retries though, which seems healthy :)